# How to plot data points in Prometheus chart with intervals between two records?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

**Actual Chart**
[image]

**Expected Chart**
[image]

Is there any relevant query that helps to pick only the data points triggered at the moment and not flowing as a series from the triggered data point until the next data point is available

or Is there any tweaks in grafana to do the same?

[image]

What I see:
- Two records which is actually generated

[image]

- There are numerous values that are auto-generated and fetched from the prometheus server; what I need is the array[0] alone from each records

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [Discrete Panel][https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/natel-discrete-panel) plugin? Fits well for event-type data points.

Comment: @YuriLachin This looks like stack; actually I want it like beats in the chart with gaps in-between the data points (if there is no events recorded)

Comment: What version of Prometheus are you using, and are these time series being exposed with timestamps? This works the way you'd expect as of Prometheus 2.0 with standard time series.

Comment: @brian-brazil v2.15.2; yea I think it is working with standard time series. Is there any way that I can achieve my task out of this. I've updated the question with two more images

Comment: Is there any prometheus query to fetch only array[0] from each records